# Convert select query to update MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to convert select to update for this query for field 'year_from':

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('.', LEFT(year_from, 4), SUBSTRING(year_from, 5)) FROM 
lc_vehicles
```

edit:
when using select i get results from 198501 to 1985.01, but when update I get 1985.0

Comment: Start by replacing `select` with `update`.  After that, it is entirely unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: What field do you want to update ?

Comment: sorry, the field is year_from. I want to update from 199901 to 1999.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
UPDATE lc_vehicles SET year_from = CONCAT_WS('.', LEFT(year_from, 4), SUBSTRING(year_from, 5))
```

Comment: when using select i get results from 198501 to 1985.01, but when update I get 1985.0

Comment: what's your field datatype ?

Comment: it was varchar (6), I've changed it to (7) and it's ok. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update your year_from field in your lc_vehicles table with some condition, you can use this query.

```
UPDATE lc_vehicles 
SET year_from = CONCAT_WS('.', LEFT(year_from, 4), SUBSTRING(year_from, 5))
where [condition];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `update` would presumably look something like this:

```
update lc_vehicles
    set ?? = CONCAT_WS('.', LEFT(year_from, 4), SUBSTRING(year_from, 5)) ;
```

The `??` is for the name of the column to be updated.

Comment: when using select i get results from 198501  to 1985.01, but when update I get 1985.0